# How to use close statement in case of reading error from file?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is:

Code::Blocks 20.3 ( compiler: mingw 9.2.0 )

The example code is:

```
module mod_close_file

implicit none

integer :: n_something

contains

function proc_calling() result(err_loc)

  logical :: err_loc

  err_loc = .false.

  open( unit = 15, file = 'data_aa.txt', action = 'read', status = 'old', err = 100 )

    read(15,*, err = 101) n_something

  close(unit = 15, status = 'keep' )

return

100 write(*,'(5x,a)') "err_loc - proc_calling - reading format - 100"
err_loc = .true.
!close(unit = 15, status = 'keep' )

return

101 write(*,'(5x,a)') "err_loc - proc_calling - reading format - 101"
err_loc = .true.
!close(unit = 15, status = 'keep' )

end function proc_calling

end module mod_close_file

program close_file

use, non_intrinsic :: mod_close_file

implicit none

logical :: err_glo

err_glo = proc_calling()

if ( err_glo ) stop "err_glo - proc_calling"

end program close_file
```

In case that the value `n_something` in the specified file is not an integer the program will report an error. In that case, is it necessary to write the close command after the return command?

Comment: Up to you entirely. If closing the file is what you want then close the file. If not, don't.

Comment: @IanBush In this case file was not closed? So if i want to close it i must use close afther return?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You can close it any time you want. Closing it and an error in reading the file are unconnected. You can use close on any open file at any point in your program.

Comment: @IanBush If the error in reading was detected i want to close file afther that and i want to go out from procedure( rest code will not be executed) and program will be stoped. In this case, if i want to do that i need to use close command which is under comment now?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand what you are trying to ask. It would be by far best to provide a short, complete program which we can compile and run that shows the problem, and a n example input file as well - all as short as possible.

Comment: @IanBush For example, if the reading value, for `n_something`, in file `data_00.txt` is not integer  the code will give a notification that the format is incorrect (label 101). If I want to close the file immediately after that notification, do I need to use `close(unit = 15, status = 'keep' )` command in place where that command is now under comment?

Comment: Yes, to close a file you need a close statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking, if you need to close the file prior stopping execution or if it will be closed automatically?
[Fortran 2008 Final Draft](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007r1.pdf) 9.5.7.1-6 (page 211):

> During the completion step (2.3.5) of termination of execution of a program, all units that are connected are closed.

2.3.5-4 (page 33):

> Normal termination of execution of an image is initiated when a STOP statement or end-program-stmt is executed.

So no you don't need to close it prior calling STOP, it should close without calling close. (personally I would do it anyway)

Comment: I understand now. But, in case that i want to close it  prior calling STOP, where is the correct position tfor `close`?Is it afther `return` just like in my example?

Comment: I don't think that there is a correct position...you can pretty much close it anywhere you want (in that function, or a dedicated function or in the main program...). In your example you call `close` **prior** `return`, if you uncomment the two `close`statements  it should be fine.